# t-sql script runs through batch file using command prompt but same does not run through jenkins

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, batch-file, jenkins

I have a SQL script which has T-SQL statements like;

```sql
:CONNECT remoteservername 

USE remotedatabsename

-- TSQL query
```

I have configured this SQL script in a batch file and that batch file in Jenkins.

My problem is when I run this batch file through command prompt it runs successfully
but when I run this batch file through Jenkins it gives me the following error message

> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server GPQUERY04, Line 1
>   Login failed for user 'Mumbai1\GPBUILD04$'.

Answer (score 0):

The service account that the Jenkins task runs under (GPBUILD04$) simply does not have permission to access the database.

Since the `$` suffix indicates that it's a local user to the machine, you'll either have to set Jenkins to run under a fixed (non virtual) account that has access to the database, or give the computer account access to the database.